# Black Diamond charset=iso-8859-1 utf 8 issue

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

I am still having issues with the black diamonds.

Take a look at this page: http://fpmnky.com/airport.php?airport_id=4131

The characters work great on the page, but in the search box type "LFLB" and you will see that the diamonds show up again.

This is in my header:

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

I also did a mysql_client_encoding() check and it said Latin1.

What else do I need to do?

Comment: Please just provide the information how the string is saved, fetched, or modified before sent

Comment: if(isset($_GET['keyword'])){
    $keyword =  mysql_real_escape_string(trim(strtoupper(htmlentities(strip_tags($_GET['keyword']))))) ;

Comment: No I mean, to the resulting string.

Comment: $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Couldn't execute livesearch");

 if($result){
     if(mysql_affected_rows() != 0){
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
```

In the ajax response, or any response in general on your website.